# sbt - not able to download assembly plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to use the sbt assembly plugin to build the fat (uber) jar. However it seems like I am not able to download the plugin itself.

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10" )
```

**Build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "DemoSparkListener",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("DemoSparkListener")
  )
```

**Error**

```
    [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.11:0.14.10
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/gaurang.shah/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_1.0/0.14.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_1.0/0.14.10/sbt-assembly-0.14.10.pom
```

Comment: You do not need to add the plugin as an application dependency, just with the `addPlugin` should be enough. Also the latest version is `0.14.10`.

Comment: initially it was added in `plugins.sbt` only, but I read somewhere on stackoverflow and added in `dependacy` as well. eitherway same result.

Comment: You do not need it in the dependencies. Those are for your code not for your build. Also, probably the error is that version of the plugin is not available for that SBT version. Try with the `0.14.10`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez made the changes. however I am still getting the similar error.

Answer (score 7):

Finally figure out the solution.

Not all the version of `assembly` plugin is available with all the version of `scala`. I didn't find any document which shows this compatibility matrix. However, you can find figure out it from here.

http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/

[image]

http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/
[image]

So this is what I did. I added the `URL Resolver` in Plugin. Which find the URL for JAR based on `Scala Version`, `SBT version` and your `Plugin Version`.

And based on above URL I choose which version of sbt version and scala version to use.

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10" )
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "DemoSparkListener",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.0",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("DemoSparkListener")
  )
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it for me too. I'm curious why this resolver is needed, I would have thought the default resolvers would be enough for it.

Comment: @pwrwr coz, this plugin is not hosted on default website.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang Shah..You are the saviour.